# How can I change the background color when I click on a radio button

Tags: javascript, html

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function changeColor() {
    var element = user.elements["group1"];

    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        if (element[i].checked == true) {

            var newColor = element[i].value;
            alert("hai");
            document.getElementById("changeColor").style.background = newColor;

        }
    }
}​
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="color"> 
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="color1" value="#990000" /><label     for="color1">Red</label>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="color2" value="#009900" /><label for="color2">Green</label>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="color3" value="#FFFF00" /><label for="color3">Yellow</label><br><br><br>
    <button onclick="changeColor()">Change</button>
```

The above HTML and JavaScript code is fine when I click on the radio button the background color is changed. It is working properly. However, my problem is that after the color change the browser will automatically refresh, which I do not want.

Comment: try  using  <input type="button">

Comment: @Ajaybeni ... or `<button type="button">`

Comment: @Ajaybeni and Pointy are correct, I'd also clean up your JS a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/czjuP/

Answer (score 1):

After click on submit button the onclick event will call. So if you send boolean value **return false** then the page is not submit here is code i am using **return false;**

```
<script>
function changeColor() {
    var element = user.elements["group1"];
    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        if (element[i].checked == true) {

            var newColor = element[i].value;
            document.getElementById("changeColor").style.backGround = newColor;
        return false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Change the onlick event add return before your changeColor() function

```
<button onclick="return changeColor();">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like your button is the only button in the form so the browser is thinking its the submit button for the form.

As pointy says you can add a type to the button, add you onclick function to a different element such as a link (with an anchor not an actual link of course otherwise you will get the same problem) or move the button outside of the form.

Comment: ... or make tbe `<button>` not be a "submit" button by setting the "type" attribute to "button"; the default in some browsers is "submit".

Comment: Yeah i move the button outside of the form but it is not working. please give me a simple example or refer me any link for this problem.

Comment: Thank you For your valuable comment - Pointy

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you use [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/):

HTML

```
<button id="btnColor">Change</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#btnColor').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#changeColor').css('background-color', $('input:radio[name=group1]:checked').val());
});
```

Comment: I highly suggest you only use `jQuery` if you have many more reasons to use it. Using `jQuery` to patch bad HTML or to fix one tiny problem isn't a good practice to get into.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the radio-buttons with a form, like this, leaving the button outside:

```
<form name="form_radiobuttons">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="color1" value="#990000" /><label     for="color1">Red</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="color2" value="#009900" /><label for="color2">Green</label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="color3" value="#FFFF00" /><label for="color3">Yellow</label><br><br><br>
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="changeColor()">Change</button>
```

This way the form won't be submitted when you click the button.

Comment: Thank you for your example - Erenor Paz -

Comment: But..did you manage to make it work? That's the important thing